# Cannot access homelab unless using proxy or vpn

Tags: networking

Ok, so I do not know if this is the right forum to post this on, but from reading some posts it seems to be the right one. I currently have a friend with a homelab that he is trying to self-host stuff on. Game servers, Websites, etc. All of my other friends can access the server just fine but for some weird reason I can't access it without using a VPN or Proxy. It works just fine when I switch networks too. I am fairly certain it has something to do with my router as none of my other devices can reach his stuff as well. I am running a netgear R6250 router and my ISP is Spectrum, though that shouldn't change anything as my friends use spectrum too. What would you guys suggest I look at first to resolve my issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does Spectrum use CGNAT (for your connection specifically)? Can other people using Spectrum access the lab? Where does `traceroute` or `tracert` for the lab IP address stop from your network? Are you trying to access it via IPv4 or IPv6 or both? Does your friend use an ISP-provided router or their own (and if it's their own, does it have 'tcpdump' available on it)?

Comment: @user1686 No, I checked and it is not using CGNAT. I did a tracert (smart suggestion btw) and it seems to stop at spectrum's server. Specifically at 142-254-141-009.inf.spectrum.com. My connection does not go any further. My friend also checked for CGNAT and he's not using it either. He owns a ISP provided router, though that is soon to change as it is limiting his options for security on his network.

Comment: How many hops does it go through before finally stopping? (Basically does it stop right at 2nd or 3rd, or does it go further?) How does that result compare with a) your traceroute to other IPs at the same ISP as your friend (try just tweaking the last number of the IP a little), and b) other people's traceroutes from their Spectrum connections to your friend's lab? In short, traceroute is easier to decipher when you have "working" examples to compare it against.

Comment: @user1686 It stops in the 2nd hop for me, this is my friend's tracert, I removed any IPs tied to a location so it shouldn't matter if I post it.

Wouldn't fit in a comment, here's a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/AQEDt0aY

Comment: `
1     4 ms    47 ms    <1 ms  dsldevice.attlocal.net [192.168.1.254]
2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  104.188.152.1

  3    16 ms     3 ms     3 ms  71.155.29.34

  4    10 ms     7 ms    15 ms  12.242.112.2

  5    44 ms    12 ms     4 ms  192.205.32.58

  6     6 ms     4 ms    17 ms  66.109.5.120

  7     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  lag-3.rcr01dllatx37.netops.charter.com [66.109.6.53]

  8    23 ms    18 ms    25 ms  lag-11.rcr01hstqtx02.netops.charter.com [24.175.51.225]

  9    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  agg1.dllbtxlb02r.texas.rr.com [24.175.49.9]`